# Is expectation maximization an example of empirical Bayes?

Tags: bayesian, expectation-maximization, empirical-bayes

I don't think I truly understand what methods are classified as "empirical Bayes". Is expectation maximization considered an example of this?

Comment: E-M is an optimization algorithm, useful for finding the maximum of likelihood functions.  EB is completely different, an attempt to mimic Bayesian analysis (and thereby gain some of the benefits thereof) w/o establishing a prior that is independent of the data.